# Name for monotone increasing then decreasing function?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for a real function that first increases and then decreases? I used the term unimodal (ooops, originally wrote it as unimodular [that explains why I could not find anything searching the web]) to describe such functions, but I am not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is called a *unimodal* function.

Answer (score 1):

For sequences of integers "unimodal" is standard - the binomial coefficients are unimodal.

I think the term could reasonably be used in the continuous case. Provide a definition for your reader just in case.

I would not recommend unimodular.